# GWT - can't load an image from the css

Tags: css, image, gwt, path

```
#main {
    background: url("images/bg_grey.png");
}
```

I have this code into my main.css but GWT can't find the image (it is into the default images folder of my GWT-project).

With JAVA there are lots methods like GWT.getModuleBaseURL(), but, into the CSS, how can i recover the correct path for my image?

Comment: Where is your default images folder?

Comment: Try `/images/bg_grey.png` ("/" in front to indicate that the `images` directory is at the root of your webapp).

Answer (score 0):

It's relative to the CSS location.

For example, if the CSS is in `/css/myStyle.css`, the path for the image would be `../images/bg_grey.png`